# CodeMirror - load file on editor on page load

Tags: javascript, filereader, pageload, codemirror

I'd like to load inside the Codemirror editor a local file on page load, I've tried using FilerReader APIs without success. I also tried to use the jquery .load() function but I can only load a file in a generic textarea not in the editor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On page load could wait for data request to complete before initializing codemirror

Since jQuery mentioned will use it for example

```
$(function(){
    $.get('path/to/codefile',  function(data){
          $('textarea#editorId').val(data);
          // now init codemirror 
    })

})
```

Comment: I've some problem with that. This function alone doesn't work. If I combine it with `$("#code").load("test.html")` it works but only if I set the code in this way: http://pastebin.com/AcdLeGmC. If I move the load function under the second script tag it doesn't work. In any case using this function break all the css style.

Comment: what is `#code`. if it's a textrea...load() shouldn't be used and should use `$.get`

Comment: need to understand that ajax is asynchronous...that's why i showed you where to initialize codemirror inside the ajax callback

Comment: I edited this way: http://pastebin.com/GFwyKTDB but loading the page in the editor i get `[object XMLDocument]` and the preview still doesn't work

Comment: OK try adding `dataType` argument `$.get('path/to/codefile',  function(data){
          $('textarea#editorId').val(data);
          // now init codemirror 
    },'text')`

Comment: Thanks, now it works. The preview still doesn't load but for this I thinks is better creating a new question.

Answer (score 1):

You can load the content to a `<textarea>` like you've done previously and then initialize `CodeMirror` instance with `CodeMirror.fromTextArea`-method.

```
var myTextArea = document.getElementById("myTextArea");
var myCodeMirror = CodeMirror.fromTextArea(myTextArea{
  lineNumbers: true,
  mode: "javascript"
});
```

For more information see [Basic Usage on CodeMirror documentation](https://codemirror.net/doc/manual.html#usage)

Comment: Trying this the file load but the editor proprieties (like lineNumbers) and the preview don't work

Comment: You can pass a second argument that contains the properties in object format to enable things like line numbers. See the edit.

Answer (score 0):

Here is sample of the code:

```
<script src="codemirror/lib/codemirror.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="codemirror/lib/codemirror.css"/>
<script src="codemirror/mode/clike/clike1.js"></script>
<script src="codemirror/mode/javascript/javascript.js"></script>

<div id="editor"> </div>
<div>
    <input type="file" onchange="localLoad(this.files);" />
</div>

<script>
   var myCodeMirror = CodeMirror(
   document.getElementById('editor'), {
      lineNumbers: true
   });

   function localLoad(files) {
       if (files.length == 1) {
            document.title = escape(files[0].name);
            var reader = new FileReader();
            reader.onload = function(e) {
              myCodeMirror.setValue(e.target.result);
            };
            reader.readAsText(files[0]);
         }
    }
</script>
```

The above one is done for `div`. If you wanted for textarea, change it like:

```
<textarea id="editor" name="field1"></textarea>

 <script>
 var myCodeMirror = CodeMirror.fromTextArea
  document.getElementById('editor'),{
  lineNumbers: true
   });
   myCodeMirror.setSize(null, 600);
 </script>
```